# Дочерний div не должен покидать родительский div когда ей управляет пользователь

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
    x += 20;
    mini.style.left = x + 'px'
  } else if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    x -= 20;
    mini.style.left = x + 'px'
  } else if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
    y += 20;
    mini.style.top = y + 'px'
  } else if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    y -= 20;
    mini.style.top = y + 'px'
  }
})
```

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mini {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="mini"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
        let x = 0;
        let y = 0;
        let boxWidth = document.querySelector("#box").offsetWidth;
        let boxHeight = document.querySelector("#box").offsetHeight;
        let elementWidth = document.querySelector("#mini").offsetWidth
        let elementHeight = document.querySelector("#mini").offsetHeight;
        document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
                if (parseInt(mini.style.left) + elementWidth === boxWidth) {
                    return false;
                }
                x += 20;
                mini.style.left = x + 'px'
            } else if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
                if ( mini.style.left === '0px') {
                    return false;
                }
                x -= 20;
                mini.style.left = x + 'px'
            } else if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
                if (parseInt(mini.style.top) + elementHeight === boxHeight) {
                    return false;
                }
                y += 20;
                mini.style.top = y + 'px'
            } else if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
                if(mini.style.top=== '0px') {
                    return false;
                }
                y -= 20;
                mini.style.top = y + 'px'
            }
        })
```

```css
    #box {
        position: relative;
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;
        border: 2px dashed black;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #mini {
        position: absolute;
        width: 140px;
        height: 140px;
        background-color: teal;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="box">
        <div id="mini" style="left: 0; top: 0;"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
const mini = document.querySelector('#mini');
const box = document.querySelector('#box');
const maxLeft = box.offsetWidth - mini.offsetWidth;
const maxHeight = box.offsetHeight - mini.offsetHeight;


function vertical(y) {
  if (y < 0) {
    y = 0;
  }
  if (y > maxHeight) {
    y = maxHeight;
  }

  return y;
}

function horizontal(x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    x = 0;
  }
  if (x > maxLeft) {
    x = maxLeft;
  }

  return x;
}
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
    x += 20;
    x = horizontal(x);
    mini.style.left = x + 'px';
  } else if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    x -= 20;
    x = horizontal(x);
    mini.style.left = x + 'px';
  } else if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
    y += 20;
    y = vertical(y);
    mini.style.top = y + 'px';
  } else if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    y -= 20;
    y = vertical(y);
    mini.style.top = y + 'px';
  }
});
```

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mini {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="mini"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).